# How can I send a string in a submit form or receive a string using the GET variable

Tags: php, html, get

I have 2 pages running and the first page has a number of radio button options. Example one of the options is:

```
Hello World
```

When I submit this to the second page and print out the GET variable on the second page, all I get is

```
Hello
```

I cant figure out if the first page sends only the array index of 0, or if the GET feature only accepts an array index of 0.

```
<?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {
         print '<td><input type="radio" name="items" value='.$row{"items"}.'>'.$row["items"].'</td>';
    }
?>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: @user3583142 PHP now allows Perl-style access to associative arrays.

Comment: `Hello world` sending as $_GET and your code PHP code doesn't match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put quotes around the `value` attribute if it contains spaces, otherwise the value ends at the space. You should also use `htmlspecialchars` in case the value contains quotes.

```
print '<td><input type="radio" name="items" value="' . htmlspecialchars($row{"items"}) . '">'.$row["items"].'</td>';
                                                  ^                                       ^
```